# Awaiting a Callback method

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm calling a third-party API which has a method that looks like this:

```
myServiceClient.Discover(key, OnCompletionCallback);

public bool OnCompletionCallback(string response)
{
    // my code
}
```

My challenge is, I have to call `Discover` because it does some work under-the-covers that I need. At the same time, I have to wait for `Discover` to complete before running my custom code. To further complicate matters, I can't just put my code in the `OnCompletionCallback` handler because I need to call the code above from a `Func` delegate. In short, I want to do this:

```
Func<SystemTask> myFunction = async () =>
{
    await myServiceClient.Discover(key);

    // my code
}
```

However, I can't do this because the third-party API uses a callback approach instead of an async/await approach.

Is there some way to make the callback approach work in an async / await world?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can do something like this

```
public Task<bool> MyAsyncFunction()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    myServiceClient.Discover("somekey", s => {
        //........
        var res = true;
        tcs.TrySetResult(res);
        return res;
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now you can await *MyAsyncFunction*

Comment: Was just writing my comment. Exactly what I was thinking. In the end, everything is still just a delegate. +1

Comment: Always aware of what async did for Promises in JS back in the day. Only today it dawned on me that we might be able to benefit from the same consumer code clarity revolution in C#!