# How to wait until a delegate is called in an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, binance

I have an async method inside BackgroundService where I need to wait until a specific condition is met within a delegate that can be called multiple times. Here's the code snippet:

```cs
private async Task BuyAndSetLimitSellOrder(string pair, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var buyOrder = await BuyAndWriteOrderToDb(pair);

    var sellOrder = await SetSellAndWriteOrderToDb(pair, buyOrder);

    var handleReceivedMessageToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var pingDelegate = await _binanceService.SubscribeToUserData(messageHandler: async userData =>
    {
        await HandleReceivedMessage(userData, sellOrder.Id, handleReceivedMessageToken);
    }, cancellationToken);

    // Wait here until a specific string is received within the HandleReceivedMessage delegate.
}
```

In the above code i want to wait until a specific string is received within the HandleReceivedMessage delegate, which can be called multiple times by a WebSocket.

Here is SubscribeToUserData code:

```cs
    public async Task<Func<Task>> SubscribeToUserData(Func<string, Task> messageHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string response = await _userDataStreams.CreateSpotListenKey();
        string listenKey = (System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CreateSpotListenKeyResponse>(response) ?? throw new FormatException("Invalid AccountInformation string")).ListenKey;
        UserDataWebSocket websocket = new(listenKey, _configuration.BinanceWssBaseUrl);
        websocket.OnMessageReceived(messageHandler, CancellationToken.None);
        await websocket.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        return () => PingSpotListenKey(listenKey);
    }
```

I tried multiple things including ManualResetEvent and while loop waiting for canncelation token but anything i put there keep blocking call to HandleReceivedMessage. Also im using [binance-connector-dotnet](https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-dotnet) for binance API calls

Comment: Are you looking to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123585/awaiting-a-callback-method

Comment: yes and there is actually example of that in library examples here, but it just doesn't work for me. It keeps waiting on TaskCompletionSoruce.Task and delegate is never called. https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-dotnet/blob/master/Examples/CSharp/WebSocketStream/UserDataWebSocket_Example.cs

Comment: Did you get any errors when debugging? Will `HandleReceivedMessage` be called if synchronous?

Comment: No, there are no errors. I don't understand what you mean by "if synchronous" because the delegate is of type `Func<string, Task>`, so it has to be a `Task`. However, `HandleReceivedMessage` will always be called if there is no code after the `SubscribeToUserData` method call.

Comment: just put Wait() to wait until task completed.
please, check this article.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149811/how-to-wait-for-async-method-to-complete

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can change the signature of the HandleReceivedMessage delegate, but here is a general pattern for using TaskCompletionSource<>.

If the Delegate is defined in 3rd party code maybe you can put the TaskCompletionSource in the userData.

Inside the HandleReceivedMessage delegate body call tcs.SetResult(true) when you meet your condition.

```
private async Task BuyAndSetLimitSellOrder(string pair, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    var buyOrder = await BuyAndWriteOrderToDb(pair);

    var sellOrder = await SetSellAndWriteOrderToDb(pair, buyOrder);

    var handleReceivedMessageToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var pingDelegate = await _binanceService.SubscribeToUserData(messageHandler: async userData =>
    {
        await HandleReceivedMessage(userData, sellOrder.Id, 
 tcs, handleReceivedMessageToken);
    }, cancellationToken);

    // Wait here until a specific string is received within the HandleReceivedMessage delegate.

  _ = await tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Yes i can, but here is the same problem as the other solutions i tried, the program stays at the line await tcs.Task; waiting for tcs.SetResult(true); in HandleReceivedMessage but HandleReceivedMessage is never called. But when i remove await tcs.Task; HandleReceivedMessage  is normally called.